# How to iteration over start and end time at 15 minute intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, iteration

How to: iterate over table rows where each row is labeled by a time.  First row would be start time, last row would be end time, and the iteration should create every row in between at 15 minute intervals.

## ie

start_time: '06:00', end_time: '07:00'

06:00

06:15

06:30

06:45

07:00

## update

```
start_time = Time.local(2013, 5, 25, 06, 00) 
  end_time = Time.local(2013, 5, 25, 20, 00) 

  begin
    start_time += 15.minutes
    puts start_time
  end while start_time < end_time
```

This returns nil...but, shouldn't...it should be returning values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure if i understand the question right, but here is an example how to generate times in 15min intervalls

```
1.9.3p392 :029 > a = Time.now
=> 2013-05-25 23:39:44 +0200 
1.9.3p392 :030 > a = a - a.sec - a.min%15*60
=> 2013-05-25 23:30:00 +0200 
1.9.3p392 :031 > b = a + 1.hour
=> 2013-05-26 00:30:00 +0200 
1.9.3p392 :032 > begin
1.9.3p392 :033 >     a += 15.minutes
1.9.3p392 :034?>   puts a
1.9.3p392 :035?>   end while a < b
2013-05-25 23:45:00 +0200
2013-05-26 00:00:00 +0200
2013-05-26 00:15:00 +0200
2013-05-26 00:30:00 +0200
```

maybe this helps a bit

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with that does just what I need.  Inspired by jethroos answer.

```
def cal_times

start_time = Time.local(2013, 5, 25, 06, 00) 
  end_time = Time.local(2013, 5, 25, 20, 00) 
     times = [start_time.strftime('%H:%M')]

  begin
    start_time += 15.minutes
    times << start_time.strftime('%H:%M')
  end while start_time < end_time

  times

end
```